# Python 2.7 Tkinter classes

Tags: python, class, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a base class with tkinter that can display the contents of any variable parsed to it.

My goal is have multiple classes that will pass variables to this class to be displayed. I have the following code thus far but I cant get it to work as intended.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

```
from Tkinter import *

class interface:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Testing tkinter and labels")
        root.geometry("600x200")

    def text(str1, str2):
        Label(root, text = str1).pack(expand=1)
        Label(root, text = str2).pack(expand=1)

        app = Frame(root)
        app.pack(side = 'bottom')
        button1 = Button(app, text="Next")
        button1.pack()

str1 = "hello"
str2 = "bye"
root = Tk()
interface(root)
interface.text(str1, str2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why it does not work? any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have this:

```
def text(self, str1, str2): #<-- you forgot self
```

And then instead of this:

```
interface(root)
interface.text(str1, str2)
```

should be:

```
int_obj = interface(root) # you need to create a variable to hold an instance of the interface you create. Otherwise, its immediately deleted.
int_obj.text(str1, str2)
```